# Bitlocker without admin privileges

Tags: bitlocker

Are admin privileges a must to be able to encrypt your files with Bitlocker?

So far I just found one comment on the internet that says it's possible without a problem but no other source to verify this.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the type of drive.

[Bitlocker FAQ for Windows 7](http://What%20credentials%20are%20required%20to%20use%20BitLocker?%20%20To%20turn%20on,%20turn%20off,%20or%20change%20configurations%20of%20BitLocker%20on%20operating%20system%20and%20fixed%20data%20drives,%20membership%20in%20the%20local%20Administrators%20group%20is%20required.%20Standard%20users%20can%20turn%20on,%20turn%20off,%20or%20change%20configurations%20of%20BitLocker%20on%20removable%20data%20drives.%20Disable%20the%20Control%20use%20of%20BitLocker%20on%20removable%20drives%20policy%20setting%20(located%20in%20Computer%20Configuration%5CAdministrative%20Templates%5CWindows%20Components%5CBitLocker%20Drive%20Encryption%5CRemovable%20Data%20Drives)%20to%20restrict%20standard%20users%20from%20turning%20on%20or%20turning%20off%20BitLocker%20on%20removable%20data%20drives.)

> What credentials are required to use BitLocker?
>
> To turn on, turn off, or change configurations of BitLocker on operating system and **fixed** data drives, membership in the local Administrators group is required. Standard users can turn on, turn off, or change configurations of BitLocker on **removable** data drives.
> Disable the Control use of BitLocker on removable drives policy setting (located in Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\BitLocker Drive Encryption\Removable Data Drives) to restrict standard users from turning on or turning off BitLocker on removable data drives.

[Bitlocker FAQ for Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-use-bitlocker-drive-encryption-tools-to-manage-bitlocker)

> What credentials are required to use BitLocker?
>
> To turn on, turn off, or change configurations of BitLocker on operating system and **fixed** data drives, membership in the local Administrators group is required. Standard users can turn on, turn off, or change configurations of BitLocker on **removable** data drives.